# "equals 0 or 1" vs. "equals either 0 or 1"

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the difference in meaning between

> i equals 0 **or** 1.

and

> i equals **either** 0 **or** 1.

?

I think both are grammatically correct, but I'm not sure if they have exactly the same meaning.

One example of "**either… or…**" structure from oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:

> Well, I think she's **either** Czech **or** Slovak.

Comment: I don't think there's really a difference. 'Either' is simply a word that one can use to introduce the comparison. As for your two examples, they both evaluate to `i={0|1}` logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually *either* does not change the meaning of the sentence and only serves to emphasize that:

- there are exactly two choices possible
- you cannot have both

In most sentences, this is already implied by *or*, and *either* is just emphatic. If the *or* by itself is inclusive, *either* will usually be exclusive (although not always):

> This license allows you to drive a car or a truck. *(you can drive both)*
>
> This license allows you to drive either a car or a truck. *(it's possible you can drive both, but it's likely to mean you can drive only one of those eg. depending on the type of the license)*

Also, in negative sentences *either* usually changes the meaning of the sentence, since negated *or* usually means "neither":

> She couldn't read or write. *(She couldn't read and she couldn't write.)*
>
> She could neither read nor write. *(She couldn't read and she couldn't write.)*
>
> She couldn't either read or write. *(She could read, but couldn't write OR She couldn't read, but she could write)*

Comment: Can 'both' be used instead of 'either' in the last example?

Comment: @Arham "She couldn't both read and write" is more likely to mean "She couldn't read and she couldn't write" to me.